# Extrude is not behaving as expected

Tags: extrude

I'm trying to extrude a section, almost like I'm scaling it, but the scaling doesn't seem to be working either. I can't find anything on why this is happening. It was working fine and then halfway through my project it isn't working!

[image]

The bottom picture is a screenshot of the tutorial I'm following along with. This is my goal. The top picture is of my project. *Extrude* pretty much just moves the selection along a dark blue axis. I've tried scaling, even by selecting <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, I've tried every extrude option (region, region normals, and individual faces) and I don't understand!

Comment: can you share you blend file here? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Can you have a clear angled picture? Because the image angle of the tutorial is OK, but image angle of your viewport is not so understandable to us/me. There is no need to have same angle as your tutorial, add some other images where your object is clearly visible!

Comment: Try switching your pivot out of  'Individual Origins' to 'Median', or '3D Cursor'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to shrink/fatten a region of an extrusion.. I don't know if this one is exactly in line with your tutorial....

1. <kbd>E</kbd> Extrude the end of the rod to the desired length of the region to be scaled
2. Now you have a set of faces whose normals you can extrude along ...  <kbd>Alt</kbd> select that face ring
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> > (Region, Vertex Normals) extrude the
   face selection along its faces' normals.

[image]

Now, if you have the Transform Orientation set to 'Normal', you can select the faces at either end of the fattened section, and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to adjust its ends.

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't seem to be working either. I wonder if its in one of my settings, that somewhere along the way I haven't returned back to normal. I think i might just tough it out for the rest of the project and myabe I'll run into the solution another day. Thank you!

Comment: @Chandler  I really don't think it can be a setting, unless it's a checkbox in the extrude panel itself.. maybe share your file to the address in the comments above? It would be a shame not to solve your problem ..

Comment: @Chandler OK, I might have got it. I notice your pivot is set to 'Individual Origins' ..  set it to something else, say 'Median'.. and make sure you've got no double verts left from earlier attempts (Ctrl+V > R)

Comment: when i change any of those, all it does is locks into an axis (typically z) and moves as if its grabbing instead of extruding

Comment: WAIT!! I DID IT!!! I DONT UNDERSTAND HOW BUT I DID IT!!!! I hit alt+e again and tried region (vertex normals) and for some reason it worked. but now I wanna know how they set that extrude as their default extrude

Comment: @Chandler phew!

Comment: @Chandler It's not simply a setting of the 'Extrude Region' operator, I don't think.. 
 It's a separate operator. you could always assign a keyboard shortcut to it (right-click on the menu item)